# Node.js process.stdin issues with typescript (tty.ReadStream vs ReadableStream)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I've used some javascript code like this to catch user inputs in Node.js:

```
if (process.stdin.isTTY) {
  process.stdin.setRawMode(true)
  process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8')
  process.stdin.resume()    

  // safe shutdown if key 'q' is pressed
  process.stdin.on('data', key => {
    if (key === 'q') {
      console.log('quit')
      ...
      process.exit()
    }
  })
}
...
```

This works fine. Now, I try to do the same in TypeScript, but here, when I try to transpile the code I get the error:

> error TS2339: Property 'setRawMode' does not exist on type 'ReadableStream'.

So, I've changed the code a little bit, I've encapsulated everything in a class with the correct type for my stdin property:

```
import * as tty from 'tty'

class MyClass {
  private stdin: tty.ReadStream

  constructor() {
    this.stdin = process.stdin
  }

  exec() {
    if (this.stdin.isTTY) {
      this.stdin.setRawMode(true)
      this.stdin.setEncoding('utf8')
      this.stdin.resume()    

      // safe shutdown if key 'q' is pressed
      this.stdin.on('data', (key:string) => {
        if (key === 'q') {
          console.log('quit')
          ...
          process.exit()
        }
      })
    }
    ...
  }
}

const myClass = new MyClass()

myClass.exec()
```

Since my class property stdin is of type tty.ReadStream the previously unknown method setRawMode is known, but now, the assignment in the constructor fails with:

> error TS2322: Type 'ReadableStream' is not assignable to type 'ReadStream'.
>     Property 'isRaw' is missing in type 'ReadableStream'.

So, what I'm doing wrong? How can I solve this? Again, in JavaScript everything works fine.

I'm using Node.js 7.5.0, TypeScript 2.1.5, @types/node 7.0.5 on ARMv7 (Raspberry Pi2)

Answer (score 3):

An easy solution is to assign the `any` type to `stdin`:

`const stdin: any = process.stdin;`

Trying to set the correct type or applying Type assertion to `process.stdin` led to further TypeScript errors (just like you describe in your question).

It seems to me that Typescript cannot handle `process.stdin` being two different types, either net.Socket or Readable, see the [docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_stdin):

> The process.stdin property returns a stream connected to stdin (fd 0). It is a net.Socket (which is a Duplex stream) unless fd 0 refers to a file, in which case it is a Readable stream.

It would be great to know what the correct solution is.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is a bit late, but this also compiles:

```
import * as tty from "tty";
if(process.stdin instanceof tty.ReadStream){
  process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
}
```

Comment: But what to do with `echo 'non-tty input' | node script.js`?

Comment: @winklerrr That my first thought.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue; upgraded to latest node v6.10.
Its API documentation is a bit hairy, but I managed to get my code corrected for build and run:

```
const tty = require('tty')
if (tty.isatty(0))
    tty.ReadStream().setRawMode(true)
```

See a working example: `npm install xvt`